# Why does "".leftPad ( 0 ) produce the same result as "".leftPad ( 1 )?

Tags: dart

Given the following code:

```
  String        indentation = ""; 
  List < int >  indents = [ 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 ];
  int           length = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; ( i <= 8 ); i++ )
    {
    if ( indents.contains ( i ) )
      {
      indentation = " ".padLeft(i);
      length = indentation.length;
      print ( "indent: $i  length: $length  indentation: '$indentation'");
      }
    }
```

I obtain the following results:

```
  indent: 0  length: 1  indentation: ' '
  indent: 1  length: 1  indentation: ' '
  indent: 2  length: 2  indentation: '  '
  indent: 4  length: 4  indentation: '    '
  indent: 6  length: 6  indentation: '      '
  indent: 8  length: 8  indentation: '        '
```

I don't think that the result of "".leftPad ( 0 ) should be the same as the result of "".leftPad ( 1 ). I can use the work-around of testing for an indent of zero. However, I believe that this is a compiler error.

Comment: Doesn't matter much what you believe if the code produces a different result than your belief.

Comment: You can complain about how dart behaves here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Comment: `" ".padLeft(i)` is different than `"".leftPad ( 0 )`

Comment: @RobertHarvey This isn't an opinion-based answer. The problem is a bug in the code that's causing it to do something other than what OP expects.

Comment: @Abion47: It doesn't look like you've read his question completely.  Read the last sentence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Again, it isn't opinion-based. OP is just wrong - it's not a compiler error, it's a programmer error. See my answer below.

Comment: I already read your answer and upvoted it.  Problem solved.  Nothing more to see here.

Comment: If you're that committed to a reopen, edit your post to remove the opinionated material and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
indentation = " ".padLeft(i);
```

`padLeft` ensures that there is at least a certain number of spaces at the start of a string and will only add more if necessary. Because you are calling it on a string that is a single space (`" "`), `padLeft(1)` will see that there is indeed one space at the start of the string and will consider its job done. Hence, `padLeft(0)` and `padLeft(1)` will do the same amount of work - none at all.

Changing `" "` to `""` produces the expected result:

```
indent: 0  length: 0  indentation: ''
indent: 1  length: 1  indentation: ' '
indent: 2  length: 2  indentation: '  '
indent: 4  length: 4  indentation: '    '
indent: 6  length: 6  indentation: '      '
indent: 8  length: 8  indentation: '        '
```